# Do a server side validation using multiple form fields

Tags: joomla

Overriding the JFormRule function "test", I need to implement a server side validation of a value of the form field against the value of another form field in the same form. I am struggling with a probably very easy thing: How can I get the value of this other form field?

Here's an extract of my form definition easyfpu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_easyfpu/models/rules">
    <fieldset
        name="details"
        label="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_DETAILS"
    >
        <field
            name="id"
            type="hidden"
        />
        <field
            name="calories"
            type="text"
            label="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CALORIES_LABEL"
            description="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CALORIES_DESC"
            size="40"
            class="inputbox validate-numfracpos"
            validate="numfracpos"
            required="true"
            hint="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CALORIES_HINT"
            message="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_NUMBER_FRAC"
        />
        <field
            name="carbs"
            type="text"
            label="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CARBS_LABEL"
            description="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CARBS_DESC"
            size="40"
            class="inputbox validate-numfracpos"
            validate="carbs"
            required="true"
            hint="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_CARBS_HINT"
            message="COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_NUMBER_FRAC"
        />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The value of the "carbs" field needs to be assessed against the value of the "calories" field. Here's my test routine "carbs.php":

```
class JFormRuleCarbs extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        // Check if value is numeric
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            $element->attributes()->message = JText::_('COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_NUMBER_FRAC');
            return false;
        }

        // Check if calories from carbs do not exceed total calories (1g carbs has 4 kcal)
        $caloriesFromCarbs = $value * 4;
        $totalCalories = $form->getValue('calories');

        if ($caloriesFromCarbs > $totalCalories) {
            $element->attributes()->message = JText::_('COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_TOOMUCHCARBS');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code `$totalCalories = $form->getValue('calories');` won't return anything, probably because it's part of a fieldset. How can I get the value of this field within this test routine?

Comment: It is more likely that the values are not filled yet, But basically your code ($form->getValue('calories')) should work.

Comment: Thanks, @Laoneo, this was a valuable hint - see my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The `$form` variable of the `test` function is not yet filled with the data from the form to be stored when the `test` function is called. Makes sense, as otherwise the potential errors you want to exclude by performing the test would already be stored.

Retrieve the required form value from the `$input` variable instead, and all is set! Here's the correct code:

```
​class JFormRuleCarbs extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        // Check if value is numeric
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            $element->attributes()->message = JText::_('COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_NUMBER_FRAC');
            return false;
        }
        // Check if calories from carbs do not exceed total calories (1g carbs has 4 kcal)
        $caloriesFromCarbs = $value * 4;
        $totalCalories = $input->get('calories', 0); // <-- THIS IS HOW IT WORKS!
        if ($caloriesFromCarbs > $totalCalories) {
            $element->attributes()->message = JText::_('COM_EASYFPU_EASYFPU_ERRMSG_TOOMUCHCARBS');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```